# Tensorflow reduce dimensions of rank 3 tensor

Tags: tensorflow, dimensionality-reduction

I am trying to build a CLDNN that is researched in the paper [here](https://36e9b848-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/tsainath/tsainath_cldnn_icassp2015.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7coIUra14fov8me7FImAp0XczhJmdMNt0Sr_E_WxwJYNpuONb2Mm0ODdEdwBq7-gU083lNqY2cNAZOFWD4wl2nNckR81Vt0VUrU_zzkkiy5CR97Px81U-UWjztvDstpu95JtqTO4Y4F9NAAklDpKiSpx1CC8TeTtnJLOEVr7VkcBSzTWBmWvtwPtI52LhES0Rb9L2I8mYTA8_dSHtg3Dyfg2skkEdKKewsSLTUKKMas5Lm03gjk%3D&attredirects=0)

After the convolutional layers, the features go through a dim-reduction layer. At the point when the features leave the conv layers, the dimensions are `[?, N, M]`. N represents the number of windows and I think the network requires the reduction in the dimension M, so the dimensions of the features after the dim-red layer is `[?,N,Q]` , where `Q < M`.

I have two questions.

1. How do I do this in TensorFlow? I tried using a weight with

   ```
   W = tf.Variable( tf.truncated_normal([M,Q],stddev=0.1) )
   ```

   I thought the multiplication of `tf.matmul(x,W)` would yield `[?, N, Q]` but `[?, N, M]` and `[M, Q]` are not valid dimensions for multiplication. I would like to keep N constant and reduce the dimension of M.
2. What kind of non-linearity should I apply to the outcome of `tf.matmul(x,W)`? I was thinking about using a ReLU but I couldn't even get #1 done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the linked paper (T. N. Sainath *et al.*: "Convolutional, Long Short-Term Memory, Fully Connected Deep Neural Networks"),

> [...] reducing the dimensionality, such that we have 256 outputs from the linear layer, was appropriate.

That means, whatever the input size is, i.e. `[?, N, M]` or any other dimensionality (always assuming that the first dimension is the number of samples in a mini-batch, denoted by `?`), the output will be `[?, Q]`, where typically `Q=256`.

As we are doing dimensionality reduction by multiplying the input with a weight matrix, no spatial information will be preserved. This means, that it doesn't matter whether each input is a matrix or a vector, so we can reshape the input to the linear layer `x` to have the dimensions `[?, N*M]`. Then, we can create a simple matrix multiplication `tf.matmul(x, W)` where `W` is a matrix with dimensions `[N*M, Q].`

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([N*M, Q], stddev=0.1))
x_vec = tf.reshape(x, shape=(-1, N*M))
y = tf.matmul(x_vec, W)
```

Finally, regarding question 2: in the paper, the dimensionality reduction layer is a linear layer, i.e. you do not apply a non-linearity to the output.